# How to write a Python program to determine correct change?

Tags: python

I'm incredibly new to programming and I'm taking my first real course (CIS 121 - Introduction to Programming Concepts) on it. My first assignment asks me to write a Python program in Replit to assist a cashier with determining correct change.The program should have one input, the number of cents to return to the customer. The output should be the appropriate change in quarters, dimes, nickels and cents, and there should ONLY be one output.

I can use integer values for my inputs and change values, and I don't have to worry about making the output plural.

I am currently at a loss. I genuinely don't know how to actually write a program now that I've been asked - I understand the concepts that the chapter covered (Variables, Variable Names and Keywords, Type Conversion Functions, Values and Data Types, Statements, Expressions, Operators, Input, Order of Operations, Reassignment, etc) and I've read the chapter multiple times, I've watched the lecture slides, and so far nothing is clicking together.

So far I've managed to figure out the Input

```
change = int(input("Please enter the number of cents (1-99):"))
```

But I can't figure out assignment statements to figure out the number of quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies. Or how to write out the output.

I'm not asking for someone to give me the answers but I would really benefit from anyone helping me or guiding me through how this works. I feel like I've just been shown the bare basics of a language and now have to speak a whole paragraph on my own.

EDIT: now I've written out the processing, but I don't know what to write for the output.

```
 if 1 <= change <= 99:
```

#quarters
quarters = change // 25
change %= 25

```
#dimes
```

dimes = change // 10
change %= 10

```
#nickels
```

nickels = change // 5

#pennies
pennies = change % 5

Comment: You need to work out the algorithm, that is the process by which you would make change, then you translate that into code.  So, ask yourself how would I do this manually.  You could always just count out the number of pennies needed, but the customer would not be happy.  So, what do you do?

Comment: Think about how you could turn the floating point numbers into integers and then do some simple math operations on them to check how many of a particular coin you need (eg. $0.79 in change, how many full quarters can it be divided into?)

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of Python operators that would be helpful for you to know:

- `//` is Python's "floor division" operator. `print(a // b)` will output a ÷ b, rounded down.
- `%` is the "modulo", or "remainder" operator. `print(a % b)` will output the remainder when you divide a by b.

Here's a sample Python script that takes in a number of days and outputs the number of years:

```py
days = int(input("Please enter the number of days:"))

years = days // 365
leftover_days = days % 365

print("Result:", years, "year(s) and", leftover_days, "days")
```

Here's me running the above script:

```bash
$ python3 test.py
Please enter the number of days:1000
Result: 2 year(s) and 270 days
```

Hopefully this is enough info for you to figure out your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You want to pick the largest coin first.  So, 99c means 3 quarters, leaving you w 24.  That’s 2 dimes…

[Modulo](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-python-modulo-operator-what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-python-solved/) operator is key here.  99 % 25 = 24.  Now, how do yet 3 quarters here?  99 -24 = 75.  Which you know has to be divisible by 25.  And it is, giving 3.

Apply same logic to 24.  What about that 4?  Can you use a nickel?  No.  Why not?

You probably need to loop on coin values (25, 10, 5, 1) to drive your logic. Tracking each time what’s left.

From personal experience:  your very first program will likely be the toughest one ever, in terms of how you perceive it.  We all, or at least me, went through that.